# JavaScript - check if the value of the property is true and return string

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have this condition that check which of these 2 properties `owner` and `tenant` is true and assigns a string to `this.productStatusReferences` according to whether `owner` or `tenant` that is true

```
if (this.projectCurrentProduct.occupancyType.owner) {
  this.productStatusReferences = 'productStatusSale'
} else if (this.projectCurrentProduct.occupancyType.tenant) {
  this.productStatusReferences = 'productStatusRent'
}
```

I'm looking for a more sophisticated solution that does the same work with Lodash or es2015 for example ?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. There is not a lot to fix here - a ternary is not in order since there are two ifs - a switch could be easier to read

Comment: What should happen if it's neither?

Comment: You should make a variable for `this.projectCurrentProduct.occupancyType`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is any improvement to be made here may be you could use lodash path checking for safety and remove the else if chain. And as already mentioned in the comments you need a case when both are not set

```
if (_.has(this.projectCurrentProduct, 'occupancyType.owner')) {
   this.productStatusReferences = 'productStatusSale'
} 
if (_.has(this.projectCurrentProduct, 'occupancyType.tenant')) {
   this.productStatusReferences = 'productStatusRent'
}
if(_.isUndefined(this.productStatusReferences))
```

Another improvement is that you can can change the occupancyType to a property so

```
  projectCurrentProduct: {occupancyType:'owner'}
```

then you can maintain a map of sorts and just set it in one go

```
 var prodcutStatusOf = {owner: 'productStatusSale', tenant: 'productStatusRent'};
 var occupancyType = this.projectCurrentProduct.occupancyType;
 this.productStatusReferences = prodcutStatusOf[occupancyType];
```